# Find matching values in a row and sum them up (excel)

Tags: excel, sumifs

Please help with the following I'm assuming SUPER SIMPLE excel solution that I can't for the life of me figure out.

In Sheet1 I have people and total:

```
People | Total
John   | (9=6+2+1)<=formula goes here
James  | 
Adam   |
```

In Sheet2 I have their info as follows:

```
People | Total
John   | 6
John   | 2
John   | 1
James  | 4
James  | 8
James  | 6
James  | 2
Adam   | 1
Adam   | 3
```

How can I have excel search for all the matching names in sheet2 e.g. John, find their scores 6,2,1 and sum them up? The names are unique to the users so no two "Johns" are alike. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUMIF` function helps here:

The formula should look similar to this

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10;Sheet1!A2;Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10)
```

This assumes that A2 is the name of one of your persons (in your example John) and that your values are in a sheet called "Sheet2" within the range A2 - B10. Just put your formula in column B2 (the one next to John)

Comment: Wait, it didn't work, sorry, I remember now I tried the vlookup function and it gives me the very first result, in this case it returns 6 instead of 9. Because 6 is listed first. If I change it to TRUE, it returns 1.

Comment: Sorry, having some issue with vlookup.

Comment: have a look at my updated answer. It's using sumif now